# IIS minimizing processes count

Tags: iis, vps

Warning: I am almost a complete newbie to server management, I have been running my own web servers for years but only at a very basic level.

With that said, I am now on a VPS host which enforces a process count limit (I suppose they're doing kernel sharing through containers)

Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5
I have about 100 concurrent users, however each user will be only loading perhaps a page every 5 minutes or so. Each page will fire, during those 5 minutes, some 5-10 http requests.

With the above load, I constantly come close or even break the 100 numprocs limit enforced by my VPS host, creating service disruptions (503 Service Unavailable)

Is there way I can reduce the number of processes, perhaps through reusing, queueing or else - to prioritize stability at the cost of speed of execution?

Thanks

ps: Edit - apparently it's SVCHOST.EXE processes that ramp up rapidly, more than W3WP.EXE ... I am clueless on what this could mean but it's probably useful information